# How to filter all rows between 2 patterns using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to filter all rows between 2 patterns which follow a numerical order.
For e.g. how could I filter all rows > 1st.7.1.* & < 1st.13.1.*

Here is how the dataframe looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could remove the constant `1st.` and use the numbers. Here I changed the range to show the effect on the the provided data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  filter(between(as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(ball, "1st.")), 0.1, 1.1))
```

```
     ball        team     batsman              bowler  nonStriker byes legbyes noballs
1 1st.0.1 New Zealand  MJ Guptill Shaheen Shah Afridi DJ Mitchell    0       0       0
2 1st.0.2 New Zealand  MJ Guptill Shaheen Shah Afridi DJ Mitchell    0       0       0
3 1st.0.3 New Zealand  MJ Guptill Shaheen Shah Afridi DJ Mitchell    0       0       0
4 1st.0.4 New Zealand  MJ Guptill Shaheen Shah Afridi DJ Mitchell    0       0       0
5 1st.0.5 New Zealand  MJ Guptill Shaheen Shah Afridi DJ Mitchell    0       0       0
6 1st.0.6 New Zealand  MJ Guptill Shaheen Shah Afridi DJ Mitchell    0       0       0
7 1st.1.1 New Zealand DJ Mitchell          Imad Wasim  MJ Guptill    0       0       0
```

```
structure(list(ball = c("1st.0.1", "1st.0.2", "1st.0.3", "1st.0.4", 
"1st.0.5", "1st.0.6", "1st.1.1", "1st.1.2", "1st.1.3", "1st.1.4", 
"1st.1.5", "1st.1.6", "1st.2.1", "1st.2.2"), team = c("New Zealand", 
"New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", 
"New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", 
"New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand"), batsman = c("MJ Guptill", 
"MJ Guptill", "MJ Guptill", "MJ Guptill", "MJ Guptill", "MJ Guptill", 
"DJ Mitchell", "DJ Mitchell", "MJ Guptill", "MJ Guptill", "DJ Mitchell", 
"MJ Guptill", "DJ Mitchell", "DJ Mitchell"), bowler = c("Shaheen Shah Afridi", 
"Shaheen Shah Afridi", "Shaheen Shah Afridi", "Shaheen Shah Afridi", 
"Shaheen Shah Afridi", "Shaheen Shah Afridi", "Imad Wasim", "Imad Wasim", 
"Imad Wasim", "Imad Wasim", "Imad Wasim", "Imad Wasim", "Shaheen Shah Afridi", 
"Shaheen Shah Afrid"), nonStriker = c("DJ Mitchell", "DJ Mitchell", 
"DJ Mitchell", "DJ Mitchell", "DJ Mitchell", "DJ Mitchell", "MJ Guptill", 
"MJ Guptill", "DJ Mitchell", "DJ Mitchell", "MJ Guptill", "DJ Mitchell", 
"MJ Guptill", "MJ Guptill"), byes = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), legbyes = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), noballs = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Answer (score 3):

We may use `parse_number` to get the numeric part and then do the `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(between(readr::parse_number(ball), 7.1, 13.1))
```

---

Or another option is to extract the substring and `filter`

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(between(as.numeric(str_extract(ball, "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$")), 7.1, 13.1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 61 × 2
   ball    team       
   <chr>   <chr>      
 1 1st.7.1 New Zealand
 2 1st.7.2 New Zealand
 3 1st.7.3 New Zealand
 4 1st.7.4 New Zealand
 5 1st.7.5 New Zealand
 6 1st.7.6 New Zealand
 7 1st.7.7 New Zealand
 8 1st.7.8 New Zealand
 9 1st.7.9 New Zealand
10 1st.8   New Zealand
# … with 51 more rows
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(ball = str_c('1st.', seq(0.1, 13.5, by = 0.1)), team = 'New Zealand')
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the numerical part and subset on this:

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(num = as.numeric(str_extract(ball, "(?<=st\\.).*"))) %>%
  filter(num > 7.1 & num < 13.1) %>%
  select(-num)
     ball
1 1st.10.9
2 1st.12.7
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ball = c("1st.7.1","1st.7.9", "1st.12.7", "1st.13.1")
)
```